# Admob no projeto

Tags: android, admob

ola 
pessoal sou leigo no assunto ainda,
Eu gostaria de saber como faço para que toda vez que o webview inicializar chame um anuncio interstitial do admob.

não consigo fazer usando um botão porque a minha pagina inicial e em html, dai não sei se funciona esse tipo de interação.